# How to move .eclipse folder?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I am using Spring System  Tool Suite. The IDE creates an additional folder named **.eclipse** in my **@user.home** folder. How can I move the **.eclipse** folder to somewhere else and make the Spring STS use the new path (instead of recreating and using a new .eclipse folder in @user.home)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't see  an option to change that location by default (it happens when the install is read-only and a user needs a writable configuration area).  You could alway try and pass in a better configuration area to `osgi.configuration.area`.  See [Setting the private configuration area](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) for the suggested option and [Runtime Options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) for more information in general.

Comment: Thanks!
I created a bat file which contains:
**"C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\STS.exe" -configuration "C:\config files"**

In the config file in **springsource\sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\configuration**, I overwrite the last line to **eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/p2/**

Everything done!