# Same locations for different eclipse installations?

Tags: eclipse

I have different eclipse installations, luna, mars, neon, 32b and 64b...

**All seems to write to my c:/users/mrsimplemind/.eclipse and .p2 folders.**

As I don't know how to force each eclipse to write to different folder, like .eclipse45 .eclipse43 etc.

I wonder what can be damaged if different eclipse uses same .eclipse .p2 folders??
Can I delete the .eclipse .p2 folders each run??

(All attempts with settings in eclipse.ini and config.ini didnt solve my issue...
**I have similar question, but it is about how to change the locations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168906/how-modify-eclipse-locations-to-prevent-write-to-user-home-directory)**)

(This question is more about "living with eclipse versions output locations" and instead understand the folders and outputs, and what if delete them!)

Comment: The .p2 folder is a local cache, it doesn't contain the state of the installation but some cached plugins; so it should be fine to have all Eclipse instances writing/reading here.

The .eclipse seems trickier: it usually contains some values for preferences. If you're fine having your preferences shared accross multiple install, it's fine.

In any case, most of the state of Eclipse is inside it's `configuration` folder and the workspace state inside the "workspace" folder. What's factorized here shouldn't take control over those 2 directories.

Comment: @Mickael thanks for clarify the folders some. The problem is that the eclipse versions are different configured, with different installed plugins etc. I m not sure how sharing same .eclipse and .p2 can f* up things.